# jQuery autocomplete plugin suggestions popup positioned incorrectely after page zoom in chrome

Tags: jquery-ui

I use jQuery autocomplete plugin.

When I visit a page and start typing in the autocomplete'd text box - suggestions show up correctly, if I zoom (in or out) the page, and type text into the same box - suggestions div is not positioned correctly.

autocomplete works fine in both IE and FF.

if I zoom the page **before** using autocomplete for the first time - autocomplete works fine.

jQuery UI: 1.9.0
Chrome: Version 22.0.1229.94 m

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced exactly the same issue and was looking for the whole week for solution.

You need to add the following css to overwrite jquery generated `position: relative`

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute!important;
}
```

I hope my answer will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

One way that helped me is to remember the last opened autocomplete input and write event handler function for browser's window's zoom to manually refresh on each resize. The same thing works for datepickers. You can even save some refreshes by setting a small timeout:

```
        var lastOpenedInput;
        myInput.on('autocompleteopen', function (event) {
            lastOpenedInput = $(event.target);
        }

        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            if (lastOpenedInput !== undefined) {
                if (lastOpenedInput.autocomplete('widget').css('display') !== 'none') {
                    lastOpenedInput.autocomplete('search');
                }
                if (lastOpenedInput.datepicker('widget').css('display') !== 'none') {
                    lastOpenedInput.datepicker('hide');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        lastOpenedInput.datepicker('show');
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        });
```